# Function Overloading in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, return-value, return-type, overloading

I just read online that as3 does not support function overloading. I looked questions related to that here in the website but the answers don't seem clear enough to solve my problem.

I tried overloading an event class the following way:

```
public function SelectEvent(type:String, selecteditem:Buyer, bubbles:Boolean=false, cancelable:Boolean=false)
        {
            super(type,bubbles,cancelable);
            selectedbuyer = selecteditem;
        }
        public function SelectEvent(type:String, selecteditem:Shop, bubbles:Boolean=false, cancelable:Boolean=false)
        {
            super(type,bubbles,cancelable);
            selectedshop = selecteditem;
        }
```

I have no idea how to make this work without overloading, which is not compatible with AS3.

Also, I have a returning function :

```
override public function clone():Event
        {
            return new SelectEvent (type, selecteditem, bubbles, cancelable);
        }
```

How do I return different item for different argument? If buyer is passed, buyer needs to be returned. If Shop is passed, shop needs to be returned. Also, Both buyer and shop are Movie Clips. Is there any way to do this by refering them as movieclips and then differentiate them?

Comment: Both Shop and Buyer could implement an Interface, selectedItem would be the type of the Interface then. No need for overloading.

Comment: @DodgerThud, what does implementing as an interface mean and how do I do it?

Comment: Check the following sites: [Tutsplus](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/as3-101-oop-introduction-to-interfaces--active-8199) and/or [Adobe](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f41.html). In short: Interfaces force Classes to implement specific functions. Objects of Classes that implement the same Interface can be used interchangeably. Interfaces are a core-principle of many programming languages, you should learn about them.

Comment: overloading is very convenient but for languages where it's not available like AS3 we can do the job just fine without it. Instead of trying to enforce something that AS3 can't do you need to adapt yourself and change your approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is polymorphism.

Instead of typing the parameter to either `Buyer` or `Shop`, you should use a super type of both.

Yes, `Object` is the super type of everything, because every object is of type `Object` (as the name implies). Both `Buyer` or `Shop` extend `Object`. There's no way around it. However, this way you can literally pass **everything** to your Event. It would look something like that.

```
public class SelectEvent extends Event
{

    private var selectedObject:Object; // I prefer camelCase (new words in the name start with capital letter)

    public function SelectEvent(type:String, selectedItem:Object, bubbles:Boolean=false, cancelable:Boolean=false)
    {
        super(type,bubbles,cancelable);
        selectedObject = selectedItem;
    }
```

As you can see, the goal here is to use a type that is compatible with both of your types. `Object` is such a type, because both of your types extend it. You can always pass a more specialised type (aka your types) where a less specialised is expected (aka Object).

---

A different solution to the same approach of using a compatible type is to use an [interface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#interface).

An interface is basically just a list of capabilities. It doesn't even include how to fulfill those capabilities. An easy example would be a drivers license. Somebody with a license is able to drive a car, park a car, etc. If a class does everything that's listed by an interface, it can implement that interface. It's like receiving the drivers license because you have proven that you can drive a car, park it, etc.
It doesn't matter what type of object is fulfilling those capabilities behind the scenes, as long as something does.

Given the definition above, a self driving car can get a drivers license, even though it is not a human and it doesn't have too much in common with humans. It's capable of doing those things that are necessary to get a drivers license. And that's all that matters.

Keep in mind that this list of capabilities can very well be empty.
So let's create an empty interface:

```
package
{
    public interface ISelectable  // start with capital I, then capital first letter of name by convention
    {

    }
}
```

Just like classes, interface are types. In this case the type your select Event expects:

```
public class SelectEvent extends Event
{

    private var selected:ISelectable;

    public function SelectEvent(type:String, selectedItem:ISelectable, bubbles:Boolean=false, cancelable:Boolean=false)
    {
        super(type,bubbles,cancelable);
        selected = selectedItem;
    }
```

In order to pass either`Buyer` or `Shop`, they have to be of that type `ISelectable`. Therefore they have to implement it:

```
public class Buyer extends Whatever implements ISelectable
```

and

```
public class Shop extends Whatever implements ISelectable
```

Notice that it doesn't matter what the super class is. Again: the interface does not care about inheritance.

---

**What's the point of using the interface, when Object does pretty much the same with less code?**

The point is that the interface is clearly defined. As said, Object allows you to pass everything. Even things that don't make any sense.

The question is why you created that Event in the first place. You want to listen for that Event in order to be notified when *something* is selected. That's what I can tell from the names you are using. But then what? what do you want to do with those selected things?

Here's an example scenario: Whenever something is selected, it should change its appearance.

What you can do now is add those things to the interface:
    package
    {
        public interface ISelectable  // start with capital I, then capital first letter of name by convention
        {
            function selected():void;
            function deselected():void;
        }
    }

Now both your classes **have to** have those methods in order implement the interface. Each one could react differently to being selected. In the following I assume they are both `Sprite` objects that change their appearance when selected or deseleceted.

```
public class Buyer extends Sprite implements ISelectable
{
    public function selected():void
    {
        alpha = 1; // fully visible
    }
    public function deselected():void
    {
        alpha = .5; // transparent
    }
```

or like this:

```
public class Shop extends Sprite implements ISelectable
{
    public function selected():void
    {
        x += 10; // move to right a bit
    }
    public function deselected():void
    {
        x -= 10; // move back
    }
```

The difference is that the interface will guarantee that the object is capable of doing the promised things. When you hire somebody with a drivers license he might be a human, a self driving car, a robot or even a monkey. You have no idea what it will be, but you have the guarantee that whatever alien it is, it will be able to drive a car, park a car, etc.

With an Object, you do not have that guarantee, because it could be everything.

A use case for the above interface could could look something like this:

with this modified Event class to retrieve the selected item and a type constant:

```
public class SelectEvent extends Event
{
    public const SELECTED:String = "selected";

    private var selected:ISelectable;

    public function SelectEvent(type:String, selectedItem:ISelectable, bubbles:Boolean=false, cancelable:Boolean=false)
    {
        super(type,bubbles,cancelable);
        selected = selectedItem;
    }
    public function get selectedItem():ISelectable
    {
        return selected;
    }
```

listening for an Event of that type:

```
addEventListener(SelectEvent.SELECTED, onSelected);

function onSelected(event:SelectEvent):void
{
    event.selectedItem.selected();
}
```

Comment: I don't like this kind of answers as they tend to be more complex than it needs to. Cheers for the efforts, but you've managed to combine all kind of techniques in something pretty simple and regular in most of the languages. Using Object as super type isn't а good approach, and polymorphism has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @AndreyPopov this is not about `most of the languages` but as3 specifically. I tried to keep this answer as little complex as possible while answering the question how this can be done with interfaces that was asked in the comments. I am creating and implementing an example interface. What techniques do you consider redundant? Polymorphism has everything to do with it because it answers the question of how to make two types compatible with each other.

Comment: I don't agree with you @AndreyPopov, the answer isn't very complex, it explains the usage of Interfaces with Examples. And if I remember correctly, Interfaces are a core concept of Polymorphism. Googling either term tends to agree with my understanding of it.

Comment: Using supertype (`Object`) is not polymorphism. You could just point out he should use interfaces and maybe a link to the references (and/or examples). You could write a whole article about interfaces, but the main question is (and/or should be) **how**, not **explain me how this practice works**. @DodgerThud - the answer starts with `Object` usage as superclass. Again - this is not polymorphism, and also polymorphism is *not only* interfaces.

Comment: @AndreyPopov if you are so keen on following links: [using Object as super type is called _inclusion polymorphism_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29) Just naming a concept and linking to an article is considered bad behaviour on SO and will result in down votes, which is reasonable because the link can break. I don't understand what you are trying to say with "**how** not **explain me how this [...] works**". Please elaborate on that.

Comment: Superclass type **check** is not polymorphism. Please read the article you've provided and you will understand what I'm talking about. Anyways, this is just pure terms. About posting a link - I'm not saying you should not write "Use interfaces, they are common way to encapsulate logic..." - it's just not a good practice to paraphrase tons of information which can be easily found online :) It's like describing how AS3 works, and what are classes, you know?

Comment: @AndreyPopov the example for inclusion polymorphism in the article is pretty much exactly the same as the question here: two classes made compatible via super type. It is polymorphism. It is good practice to paraphrase the information, that's the entire point of this website. Merely stating that an interface solves the problem is not considered an answer here. After all, if it's so easy to find this on the internet why didn't you provide a link in an answer instead of expressing your feelings about mine?

Comment: @null thanks a lot for explaining it all so briefly. It's all clear now and it works well as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can't overload function in as3 but you can pass the parameter as Object and check the type like that:

```
public function SelectEvent(type:String, selecteditem:Object, bubbles:Boolean=false, cancelable:Boolean=false)
    {
        super(type,bubbles,cancelable);
        if(selecteditem is Shop) {
            selectedshop = selecteditem as Shop
        } else if(selecteditem is Buyer) {
            selectedbuyer = selecteditem as Buyer
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nice and pretty straightforward, but casting to classes is pretty bad thing to do, as it can fail. Using interfaces is the true :)

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are robust and applicable to multiple programming languages, but this approach is also somewhat common in AS3 and requires no type casting:

```
public class SelectedEvent {
    public static const SELECTED_BUYER:String = "selectedBuyer";
    public static const SELECTED_SELLER:String = "selectedSeller";

    public var buyer:Buyer;
    public var seller:Seller;

    public function SelectEvent(type:String, bubbles:Boolean=false, cancelable:Boolean=false)
    {
        super(type,bubbles,cancelable);
    }
}

//[...]
var evt:SelectedEvent = new SelectedEvent(SelectedEvent.SELECTED_BUYER);
evt.buyer = selectedBuyer;
dispatchEvent(evt);
```

The downside to this approach is obviously that **it can't force you to set values to the properties before dispatching the event**. I prefer this approach when I have a large number of events that logically seem they should be grouped under the same class, but require different properties for each event.

Alternatively, if for some reason you need to use the same event regardless of whether the user selected a buyer or seller, you could handle it like this:

```
private function selectedEventHandler(event:SelectedEvent):void {
    if (event.buyer) {
         //do stuff here
    } else if (event.seller) {
         //do other stuff here
    }
}
```

which again obviates the need for type casting (although you could argue this approach isn't any better)

I think Adobe does it like this:

```
public function SelectEvent(type:String, selectedBuyer:Buyer = null, selectedSeller:Seller = null, bubbles:Boolean=false, cancelable:Boolean=false)
    {
        super(type,bubbles,cancelable);
        this.buyer = selectedBuyer;
        this.seller = selectedSeller;
    }
}
```

but I hate messy constructors.

Comment: Thanks for writing out this. It was helpful.

Comment: No problem, glad to help! If you think it was helpful, an upvote would be appreciated, but I don't remember if accounts with low rep are allowed to upvote answers. Good luck with your project!

Comment: I'd do it once I have 15 rep :)